# Godot Ui Container not acting as expected

Tags: godot4

I am trying to make a table with multiple rows, with each row having a LineEdit and a Button filling the width of the control (like every table row does) and then use the whole scene as a control and load it in other scenes.
The VFlowContainer is anchord and is filling the width of it's parent.

[image]

But the 2 HBoxContainers do not fill the width of their parents(which is VFlowContainer).

[image]

I tried the container sizing of HBoxContainer, but Fill doesn't work and also expand button is not active.
I know I can set the minimum size of those LineEdits and Buttons to make the VFlowContainer grow horizontally but since I need it to be a responsive control, the rows should fill the whole width automatically not by a specific vlue.
Does anybody know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The `VFlowContainer` does not do that. It does not stretch the column, instead it uses the contents to define the size of the column.

As far as I can tell none of the build-in `Container`s does what you want out of the box.

Comment: I think you are right about VFlowContainer, but I'm not sure about "none of the built-in Containers not doing the job". I used BoxContainers and it worked. At least it gives me what I am expecting. Thanks

Comment: @amirmola as long as the children fit, yes, they will behave as you expect. But they won't flow to a second line when the children don't fit.